# Drawing ROC from the given classifier

Tags: r

I have a classifier with the below quality information, but I don't have any data:

TP :325/TN :200/FP :275/FN :200

Is there any solution that assists me to find regression model based on above information. I need to draw ROC.

Answer (score 0):

An ROC curve plots the relationship between specificity and sensitivity (outcomes from a classifier with a certain cutoff point), over many different cutoff points. So basically, the above describes a single point on your curve.

Without known outcome data and the predicted probability from your algorithm, over that same data, it is theoretically impossible to generate new points on that curve.